# How to iterate a list <ClassUsingEntityAnnotationOfSpring>?

Tags: java, spring, entity, loops

I am trying to iterate a list of (Users) and I am receiving this error:

```js
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to br.com.meupacote.model.Usuario
at
```

Users is a class with @Entity annotattion. It's a table of my database.

I trying to interate this 2 forms:

```js
List<Deg> lista = new ArrayList<Deg>();

degV.forEach(d -> {
  Deg dgust = Degustacao.builder().codProduto(d.getId().getCodProduto())
      .dataInicio(d.getDtaInicio())
      .dataFim(d.getDtaFim()).build();
  lista.add(dgust);
});

for (Usuario d : degV) {
  Deg dgust = Degustacao.builder().codProduto(d.getId().getCodProduto())
      .dataInicio(d.getDtaInicio())
      .dataFim(d.getDtaFim()).build();
  lista.add(dgust);
}
```

Sorry for my english.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doesn't matter whether it is annotated with @Entity the error you are receiving is because in the example degV is a collection which is not compatible with class Usuario. So degV variable must be of should be List<Usuario> type.

Comment: Thank you for responding.
But I justly want to turn List<Usuario> into List <Deg>.
Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was not returning a Usuario List in the method that accessed my table. Since u was only selecting a few columns, I was returning an object list, so the cast error. I solved the problem by returning all the fields of the tables and selecting only the ones I wanted during the iteration to build the Deg obj.